# How to embed VAST with audio web player?

Tags: html, ads, vast, google-ima

I'm building a web music player. I'm using a https://howlerjs.com as a player library.
I need to embed Ads to the music player. I get a tag url like this

```
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?iu=......
```

I've been searching via Internet for 2 days but found nothing. I found that Google has a **IMA SDK** but I've found only a document shows how to embed Ads with Video player -  https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side

Please help.

Comment: Could your share your fulltag url (without ids if you prefer) to check its structure ?